# AS3 socket client doesn't send policy file request to server

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, flash

im trying to write an AS3 client. I can establish the connection but the Event.Close is called after the first answer of the server. I guess it is because of the policy file.

The problem is that my server doesn't receive the policy file request. I have tried listening on my port and the 843 port.

This is how I do the connection:

```
    Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        Security.allowDomain("*");              
        Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:5555");
        socket = new Socket();

        socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler); 
        socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler); 
        socket.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler); 
        socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, dataHandler);
        socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler); 

        try 
        { 
            trace("Trying to connect to " + serverURL + ":" + portNumber + "\n"); 
            socket.connect(serverURL, portNumber); 
        } 
        catch (error:Error) 
        { 
            trace(error.message + "\n"); 
            socket.close(); 
        }
```

Comment: In my socket app I don't do the following: `Security.allowDomain("*"); Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://127.0.0.1:5555");` and it asks for policy file by itself.

Comment: I have been testing again and I do get the policy file request when I use chrome with a normal flash player. But I dont get it when I use a different browser or flash player. Can someone help?